# Testing with curl works, but the same POST fails as `httptest.NewRequest`

Tags: go

With this curl command I'm able to create Parts in my backend. The request is validated successfully.

`curl -XPOST -H"Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/v1/parts/ -d'{"custom_id":"test"}' -D -`

But if I on the other hand try to recreate that request in a test, then it's not considered a valid request:

**Error message:**
"Unable to bind request to parts"

I'm not able to see why the test fail when the curl works. Can anyone spot the error?

**handlers/parts_test.go**

```
func TestCreatePart(t *testing.T) {
        // Setup
        e := echo.New()

        reqBody := strings.NewReader(`{"custom_id": "custom"}`)

        req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/parts", reqBody)
        rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
        c := e.NewContext(req, rec)

        if assert.NoError(t, CreatePart(c)) {
                assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
                assert.Equal(t, "userJSON", rec.Body.String())
        }
}
```

**handlers/part.go**

```
 func CreatePart(c echo.Context) error {
      resp := renderings.PartResponse{}
      pr := new(bindings.CreatePartRequest)

      if err := c.Bind(pr); err != nil {
              resp.Success = false
              resp.Message = "Unable to bind request to parts"
              return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, resp)
      }

      if err := pr.Validate(c); err != nil {
              resp.Success = false
              resp.Message = err.Error()
              return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, resp)
      }
```

**internal/bindings/parts.go**

```
  package bindings

  import (
          "fmt"

          "github.com/labstack/echo"
  )

type CreatePartRequest struct {
          CustomID string `json:"custom_id" xml:"custom_id" form:"custom_id" query:"custom_id"`
  }

func (pr CreatePartRequest) Validate(c echo.Context) error {
          errs := new(RequestErrors)
          fmt.Println("pr: ", pr.CustomID)
          if pr.CustomID == "" {
                  errs.Append(ErrCustomIDEmpty)
          }
          if errs.Len() == 0 {
                  return nil
          }
          return errs
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `req.Header.Set(echo.HeaderContentType, echo.MIMEApplicationJSON)` it might be related to the content type header.